# ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore error on release

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, native

I've react native app, which I want to release to app store connect. When I build app to simulator, it's all ok, but when I choose 'Generic iOS Device', and click 'Product' -> 'Archive', final I've error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/__/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/--butmameeeywydzhbrsswxxghtgte/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/-/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/__/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/--butmameeeywydzhbrsswxxghtgte/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/-/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseInstanceID'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/__/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/--butmameeeywydzhbrsswxxghtgte/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/-/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseMessaging'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/__/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/--butmameeeywydzhbrsswxxghtgte/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/-/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/__/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/--butmameeeywydzhbrsswxxghtgte/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/-/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Protobuf'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/__/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/--butmameeeywydzhbrsswxxghtgte/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/-/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/nanopb'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/__/Desktop/Projects/-/react-client-app/ios/../ios/RNFirebase'
ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried everything, but error still showing when I try to release app.

I tried:

- removing node_modules, package-lock.json, pods folder, podfile.lock and install dependencies again
- add RNFirebase in Target dependencies
- add $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase in Framework/Header/Library search paths in Build Settings
- add libFirebaseCore.a, libFirebaseInstanceID.a, libFirebaseMessaging.a in 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries'
- check show and shared checkboxes with Firebase, FirebaseAnalytics, FirebaseCore, FirebaseInstanceID, FirebaseMessaging on 'Product' -> 'Scheme' -> 'Manage Schemes'
- add Firebase, FirebaseCore, FirebaseAnalytics, FirebaseAnalyticsInterop, FirebaseInstanceID, FirebaseMessaging, RNFirebase in 'Product' -> 'Scheme' -> 'Edit Scheme'

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '11'

target '__' do
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

I wan't to archive app to App Store Connect and Crashlytics. Please, help. Many hours spent on this have had no effect

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you're opening the .xcworkspace file and not .xcodeproject correct?

You're probably ahead of me but something that worked when I had issues:

Close XCode

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Delete node_modules, Pods folder, podfile.lock AND your app.xcworkspace file

Remove everything from podfile except Firebase/Core

`pod install`

Open new xcworkspace file

Run build (not archive)

Wait for completion (or error)

Add other pods back to podfile

`pod install`

Clean build folder

Archive

Also ensure path in header search paths is set to recursive